# How to set encoding in PHP FPDI library

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

How to set UTF-8 encoding in php library named FPDI?
Here's library: https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/manual/

The code:

```
$pdf = new Fpdi();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->setSourceFile('PdfDocument.pdf');
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
 
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 100);

$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
$pdf->SetTextColor(255, 0, 0);
$pdf->SetXY(30, 30);
$pdf->Write(0, 'Zażółcić gęślą jaźń');

$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: For clarification, the `FPDI` library uses either `FPDF`, `TCPDF`, or `tFPDF` in order to add PDF file importing support to them. FPDF does not support UTF-8 encoding. `tFPDF` is a replacement for `FPDF`, that adds UTF-8 support. However you will still need to add your UTF-8 fonts manually or to your `fonts/unifont` directory.

Comment: Did you tried mPDF? https://mpdf.github.io/ It bases on FPDF but is a bit more easy to use. You could also set it there in the constructor using `'mode' => 'utf-8'`. May take a look

Answer (score 1):

You could add new font with proper letters

```
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSansCondensed.php');
$pdf->SetFont('DejaVu', '', 10, '', false);
```

Then in regard to `FPDF` library that is used by `FPDI`:

There possible encodings are:

```
cp1250 (Central Europe)
cp1251 (Cyrillic)
cp1252 (Western Europe)
cp1253 (Greek)
cp1254 (Turkish)
cp1255 (Hebrew)
cp1257 (Baltic)
cp1258 (Vietnamese)
cp874 (Thai)
ISO-8859-1 (Western Europe)
ISO-8859-2 (Central Europe)
ISO-8859-4 (Baltic)
ISO-8859-5 (Cyrillic)
ISO-8859-7 (Greek)
ISO-8859-9 (Turkish)
ISO-8859-11 (Thai)
ISO-8859-15 (Western Europe)
ISO-8859-16 (Central Europe)
KOI8-R (Russian)
KOI8-U (Ukrainian)
```

The string that was sent  to pdf was in UTF-8 (it was checked by  `mb_detect_encoding` function) and there was a need to convert it with cp1250.

```
$str = iconv('UTF-8', 'cp1250', 'zazółcić gęślą jaźń');
```

Another solution would be to try to use:

```
$pdf->SetFont('freeserif', '', 14, '', true);
```

UPDATE PRO TIP:

In case of problems with fonts - check out first if the font is installed on your linux server.

Comment: What's in the `DejaVuSansCondensed.php` you're referring to when adding the font?