# tcpdf marathi font not working properly

Tags: laravel, tcpdf

i am using tcpdf, i want to print marathi font. but it not print properly.

i want ot print like this 
[image]

but it display like[image]
please help me
i try by adding devnagari font but still getting this.
if i echo this text in html it display properly but in tcpdf not working

Comment: here u have answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772714/how-to-set-encoding-in-php-fpdi-library

Comment: thank you sir for reply. still it not working

Comment: believe me that this response contains solution of your problem