# Display Error: Question marks instead of Arabic text in PDF

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, arabic, arabic-support

Am using this PDF library https://github.com/thujohn/pdf-l4 to generate PDF in PHP (Laravel)

When I try something like:

```
$html = '<html>';
   $html .= '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />';
   $html .= '<body>مرحبا</body>';
$html .= '</html>';
return PDF::load( utf8_decode($html) , 'A4', 'portrait' )->show();
```

I get **`?????`** as output instead of **`مرحبا`**

When I remove **utf8_decode**
I get empty response.

Can anyone tell me how I can display Arabic characters in PDF using PHP .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had the same problem with polish letters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772714/how-to-set-encoding-in-php-fpdi-library

Answer (score 0):

You can try this package, i used it before and it supports Arabic [dompdf/dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf)

[this comment on github explains all the steps](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/712#issuecomment-171533682)