# Korean characters become "???" after exported using dompdf laravel

Tags: laravel, unicode, dompdf

I using dompdf for laravel, the problem is the Korean characters can show properly in html but it's turn into "???" when exported into pdf.

Korean characters in header and footer can show properly using `$canvas->page_script()` but Korean characters in `loadHTML` not showing properly.

Can someone help me?

```
        $pdf->loadHTML($doc_content);
        $pdf->output();
        $dom_pdf = $pdf->getDomPDF();
        $options = new Options();
        $options->set('isPhpEnabled', true);
        $options->set('isRemoteEnabled', true);
        $options->set('defaultFont', 'UnShinmun');
        $dom_pdf->setOptions($options);
        $canvas = $dom_pdf->get_canvas();
        //$canvas->page_text(0, 0, "Page {PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}", null, 10, array(0, 0, 0));

        $canvas->page_script('              
            $font = $fontMetrics->get_font("UnShinmun");
            $size = 11;

            $pageText = "'.$doc_title.'";
            $y = 30;
            $x = $pdf->get_width()-30- $fontMetrics->get_text_width($pageText, $font, $size);
            $pdf->text($x, $y, $pageText, $font, $size, array(.302, .302, .302));

            $pageText = "'.$doc_num.'";
            $y = 44;
            $x = $pdf->get_width()-30- $fontMetrics->get_text_width($pageText, $font, $size);
            $pdf->text($x, $y, $pageText, $font, $size, array(.302, .302, .302));

            $size = 9;

            $pageText = "Page " . $PAGE_NUM. " of " . $PAGE_COUNT;
            $y = $pdf->get_height() - 38;
            $x = $pdf->get_width()-30- $fontMetrics->get_text_width($pageText, $font, $size);
            $pdf->text($x, $y, $pageText, $font, $size, array(.302, .302, .302));

            $pageText = "'.($type=='Form'?'':'Version No.: 01').'";
            $y = $pdf->get_height() - 38;
            $x2 = 28;
            $pdf->text($x2, $y, $pageText, $font, $size, array(.302, .302, .302));

            $y = $pdf->get_height() - 24;
            $pageText = "V' . '1.00' . '";
            $pdf->text($x, $y, $pageText, $font, $size, array(.302, .302, .302));               
            $pdf->line(28,795,567,795,array(.302, .302, .302),1); #footer hr
       ');
        //$pdf->render();
        $output = $pdf->output();
```

Comment: here you have answer to this kind of problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772714/how-to-set-encoding-in-php-fpdi-library

Comment: @AdamKozlowski that's not solved my problem, they not have support for Korean characters.

Comment: did u read answer, does it work?

Comment: @AdamKozlowski yes, already read it but it's still not working with dompdf. while in fpdf as I know it can't set header and footer automatically like dompdf

Comment: did u install font?

Comment: @AdamKozlowski yes, I already install the font

Comment: what is the result, the problem was solved?

Comment: @AdamKozlowski, korean character in content not showing, while in footer and header showing.

Comment: so while in footer and header showing problem is SOLVED! it means that there is another problem/error in body. Maybe encoding form database?

Comment: @AdamKozlowski in database it's saved in html format, and it can shown in website normally but no when exported. I already tried to change the encoding to UTF-8 and korea encoding, none works.

Comment: I have no other idea how to help you. I still believe that my answer is correct and it include solution of your problem.

Comment: @AdamKozlowski no, it's not. Your solution was to change my package to fpdf instead of using dompdf. And in fpdf can't set header and footer automatically like dompdf can do. Anyway thank you for your answers.

Comment: I did my best. Good luck.