# dompdf is showing utf-8 language all words (?) question mark

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

i am using dompdf with laravel 5.6 and when i export my pdf it shows all the charachters of that language in a question mark formart like this

```
????????????????
```

i read to give it font  DejaVu to be fixed but that didnt worked out
here is my code

```
    <h1 class="test">مثال(something in persian language)</h1>
```

and css of

```
.test {
        font-family: 'DejaVuSans';
        font-size: 25px;
    }
```

and controller

```
 public function downloadPDF($id){
    $invoices = invoices::find($id);

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('admin.invoices.pdf', compact('invoices'));
    return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');

}
```

Comment: In your templates, set the UTF-8 Metatag: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>`

Comment: did that yet all of them are ???? .not working

Comment: I think that here is similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772714/how-to-set-encoding-in-php-fpdi-library

Comment: the library he is using is different from mine i read that but that didnt helped too unfortunatly

Comment: Could you try the following font? It helped me. ```<style>body { font-family: DejaVu Sans, sans-serif; }</style>```